# Mail sharing option not visible

Tags: ios, sharekit

I am using ShareKit in my iphone app I am currently developing and would like to implement
sharing by Facebook, Twitter, Tumblr and by Mail. I have set up everything but the problem is that all of theese options are visible in sharing menu that is displayed when custom share button is tapped except the Mail option so i am not sure what i am doing wrong.

In SHK.m class file in favoriteSharersForType method i've set up favorite sharers this way:

```
favoriteSharers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"SHKFacebook", @"SHKTwitter", @"SHKTumblr", @"SHKMail", nil];
```

and only Mail options is not visible, i also tried to set it up with only Mail option as test:

```
favoriteSharers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"SHKMail", nil];
```

but even then Mail option isn't displayed.

Does anyone know what i might be doing wrong, any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: in the first codeline you wrote `@""SHKMail"` there is a double "" after the @. Remove one of the " but i don't think that fixes the problem

Comment: Additional did you `#import "SHKMail.h"` ?

Comment: Yeah, that was a typo with double "" in my post so that's not a problem. Where should i import SHKMail.h? Somehow i don't think that would solve the problem since i am not using just SHKMail class but the whole ShareKit action sheet and i am not importing manually SHKTwitter or SHKFacebook for example and those services are displayed just fine in the sharing menu :/ Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well are you running your code on simulator or device? if you are running your code on device do you have any email account setup in that device?

Comment: That was it, i was running it on the device on test ipad and there wasn't any email account set up on it. Thank you for your tip Saurabh!